# Cocoa на OS X в Xcode: почему, если в окно добавить WebView, то при запуске оно станет пустым, вообще без контролов?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa, webkit

Создал проект. Xcode, Cocoa, Swift (не думаю, что ЯП имеет значение) 
Кинул Button и Label.
Запустил. Кнопка и надпись на месте.
Кинул WebView.
Запустил. Пусто - ни кнопки, ни надписи, ни WebView. Подождал немного, "потягал" окно туда-сюда (вдруг проблемы с перерисовкой). Все равно пусто.
Убрал WebView.
Запустил. Кнопка и надпись опять на месте.

Что это может быть?
Работал с разными "движками" браузеров, на разных ОС, платформах, и никогда ничего подобного не встречал.
И Google тоже не знает.
По опыту с WinForms мог бы предположить, что по умолчанию WebView заполняет все окно и закрывает контролы.
Но, во-первых, я пробовал Hidden, и ничего не изменилось.
Во-вторых, в Interface Builder видно, что WebView имеет "фиксированные" координаты, а не заполняет весь контейнер.
<strike>В-третьих, как вообще хваленые дизайнеры Apple могли допустить, что дизайн окна в Interface Builder до такой степени отличается от его вида при запуске, и это в приложении уровня Hello World? Это и есть то, что я должен захотеть лизнуть? :) А если я лизну, WebView появится? Это у них механизм перерисовки так работает? Или это как-то связано с безопасностью (серфинга через WebView), по тому же принципу, что и сканирование отпечатков пальцев?</strike>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего Вы не подключили необходимый фреймворк `WebKit`. Подключите как указал на картинке и все появится: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, но неясно, какая вообще связь с другими контролами в окне. Что там происходит, как оно работает? "Мак" - это далеко не первая ОС, для которой я пишу софт, но я ни разу ничего подобного не встречал.

Comment: А почему фреймворк автоматически не подключается, аналогично тому, как это происходит в Visual Studio при добавлении контрола в форму? Вот вам и Apple...

Comment: не видел там ни одного стандартного контрола, который бы имел зависимости. Тот же WebView.